# Windows sees UDF partition as read-only and 100% full after writing to it in Linux

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, udf

I formatted a partition on an external HDD as [UDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format), to be able to use it in both Arch Linux and Windows 7 without everything getting executable as it does with NTFS.
I can read from, and write to the partition just fine when using Linux, but in Windows the partitions is seen as having 0 bytes free of 874GB ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKDGI.jpg)). Also every file and directory has a read-only attribute that can't be removed, even as administrator ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/272v1.jpg)).

What I tried:

1. Formatting with `makeudffs`. Result: I could read+write in Linux; after booting into Windows I got the problems described above.
2. Formatting with `format /FS:UDF`. Result: I could read+write in Windows; after booting into Linux I could read+write there too; booting into Windows again after that I got the problems described above.

Comment: What Linux kernel version and what udftools (mkudffs) version are you using? Do you specify any `--media-type=` option when creating the filesystem?

Comment: @grawity I'm on kernel version 5.1.3, with udftools 2.1
I specified --media-type=hd